# ios hide status bar with animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I want to disable navigation bar animation when page change.,

root viewController

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];,
}
```

pushed viewController

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return NO;
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];,
}
```

If both pages statusBarHidden is equal to NO or YES this method work but when i disable one of them a problem occurs. I could not upload image because of my reputation very low please check link for image.
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=154038544933435&set=a.154038594933430.1073741827.100009818700445&type=1&theater

Comment: How do you push the next view controller? `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO]`

Comment: like this `[self.navigationController pushViewController: myController animated:YES];`

Comment: you need to invoke [super viewWillAppear:animated]; and the "animated:animated" doesn't make sense since this "antimated" has nothing to do with the appearnce of the navigationbar

Comment: if you don't invoke super viewWillApear then you will have unexpected results, fix that first and then come back and tell us what happens

Comment: Don't know if I understood properly the question... If what you want is to prevent navigation bar animation when changing the view controller, then just set NO to animated when you push the next view controller

Comment: @PabloA. but user can change page with finger slowly

Comment: `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;`

Comment: @Larcerax sorry i edited my codes

Comment: perfect, let me look at this in more detail

Comment: @PabloA. ohh thanks but i want this settings in my project. can i fix problem without disable `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;` this method

Comment: Sorry, the link to the image is not working for me.

Comment: @Kie please check again

Comment: Why in the settings? You can build your custom `UINavigationController` subclass, disabling gesture recognizer and use use it for all your navigation controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should used this it work for me on tab gesture

```
NSTimer *timer;
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden == YES)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(hideStatusbar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

calling methods

```
-(void)hideStatusbar
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `prefersStatusBarHidden` should do the trick. No need to override `viewWillAppear:animated`, because iOS animates automatically from one status bar state to the next.

Be sure to set "View controller-based status bar appearance" in your Info.plist to YES.

[image: Set this to YES]

As far as the navigation bar is concerned. If you use storyboards and use Segueues you can transition from one Navigation Controller to the another. If navigation Controller A has a visible Navigation Bar and Navigation Controller B has a hidden Navigation Bar, iOS will automatically animate the Navigation Bar away for you.